# Excel List Lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two lists. I'm trying to write a formula, so that excel will look in one list to see if it can find any of the information in the other list, and if so, it will display X. So that if anyone of the names on this list becomes present in this other list, the cell will display x. Thanks for the help

Comment: Research `LOOKUP`, `VLOOKUP`, `INDEX`, and `MATCH`, and search [SU].  Try to solve this yourself (or find an equivalent question that's been answered; there's probably at least one).  If you get stuck, tell us what progress you've made and where you're having trouble.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Say we have the short list in column **A** and the long list in column **D**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,$D$1:$D$21,0),"")
```

and copy down. Then in another cell enter:

```
=IF(COUNT(B:B)>0,"X","")
```

[image]